# Populating an array with fields from a string

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I have this string that contains the following quote-contained, comma-separated values:

```
"field","anotherfield","yetanotherfield"
```

I need to populate an array with the content of these fields, without the quotes.

What I'm currently doing is:

```
$string = str_replace('"', NULL, $string);
```

and then

```
$array = explode(',', $string);
```

It works, but it breaks when there's a comma inside any field. How can I prevent this?

Comment: Maybe if you reverse the process. First explode, then delete quotes.

Comment: You could use another symbol like ";"

Answer (score 0):

first, trim `"` from the start and end of string.

```
$string = trim('"field","anotherfield","yetanotherfield","other, another"', '"');
```

and after explode `","` between values you need.

```
$array = explode('","', $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

To parse entire CSV file into an array you could use [str_getcsv](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) function:

```
$array = array_map( 'str_getcsv', file( 'path-to-file/file.csv' ) );
```